# Machine Learning and Computer Graphics

Tags: optimisation

Is there currently anyone working on a link between these two fields? I have a hunch that, due to the repetitive nature of sampling, there could be a good bit to gain in the area of ray tracing using Machine Learning techniques, but I'm interested in finding out more and getting involved if there's a group out there doing this.

Comment: I have seen a few people apply machine learning to BRDF's.  Here's one such thing: http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v42/issue_1/IJCS_42_1_04.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group from UC Santa Barbara published the Siggraph 2015 paper [A Machine Learning Approach for Filtering Monte Carlo Noise](http://cvc.ucsb.edu/graphics/Papers/SIGGRAPH2015_LBF/) describing a technique which trains a neural network to select filtering parameters for path tracing. The paper details the structure of the neural network, the filter parameters used and how several secondary features are pre-computed to feed the neural network.